# login as rsh in rhel 6 without entering password

Tags: redhat, pam, rsh

I need to be able to login to a RHEL 6 server using rsh (please don't flame me about security, it's irrelevant in this particular instance) as root without having to enter a password.  My procedure for setting this up works great in RHEL 5.x, but does not work in RHEL 6.  I suspect this has something to do with PAM, but I'm inexperienced with how to use PAM.  Can someone help me with this?

/etc/pam.d/rsh

```
auth      required   pam_rhosts.so
auth      required   pam_nologin.so
account   include    common-account
password  include    common-password
session   required   pam_loginuid.so
session   include    common-session
```

/etc/pam.d/rlogin

```
auth      required   pam_nologin.so
auth      [user_unknown=ignore success=ok ignore=ignore auth_err=die default=bad] pam_securetty.so
auth      sufficient pam_rhosts.so
auth      include    common-auth
auth      required   pam_mail.so
account   include    common-account
password  include    common-password
session   required   pam_loginuid.so
session   include    common-session
```

Thanks!

Comment: If possible I would suggest you use SSH and keys, even if security is not an issue. SSH is better supported in general, and key-authentication works without any hacks.

Comment: I would love to!  the problem is I'm in a test environment and the proprietary testing tools that I've been given use rsh exclusively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you edit `/etc/pam.d/rlogin` it says at the top:

```
# For root login to succeed here with pam_securetty, "rlogin" must be
# listed in /etc/securetty.
```

After adding `rlogin` at the end of `/etc/securetty` remote login works without password.

I also found this [explanation of how PAM works](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/how-pam-works) useful.

Comment: This is old, but I wanted to respond.  This was the solution.  It was a PAM issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problems. Those two commands made it working:

```
# chkconfig rsh on
# service xinetd restart
```

Answer (score 3):

I may be dragging up an old question, but since I was banging my head on this one as well, I thought I'd post what I did to solve it.

Looks like for some reason pam_rhosts.so on RHEL6 does not allow root, so after the `auth sufficient pam_rhosts.so` line in `/etc/pam.d/rlogin` I added:

`auth sufficient pam_rootok.so`

which may or may not be the "right" way, but seems to do the trick at least.

Answer (score 0):

J.Newman's solution worked for me. For other r services, eg rsh and rexec, this change is also required to relevant file in combination with an entry of (may not be present or may not be set to sufficient):
auth sufficient pam_rhosts.so